# How to add OnitemClickListener in ArrayList without ListView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I want to make a dashboard in android studio.I use two xml for making dashboard main_activity and list_item activity.In the coding session i used model class adapter and also main class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<DashModel> dashModelArrayList;
DashAdapter dashAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv1);

    dashModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String heads[] = {"Jobs", "My Profile", "Messages", "Applied Jobs", "Resume", "Settings"};

    String subs[] = {"12 new jobs found", "75% complete", "2 new messages", "3 applies jobs", "Edit resume", "Set preferences"};

    int images[] = {R.drawable.find_jobs, R.drawable.profile, R.drawable.messages, R.drawable.applied_jobs,
            R.drawable.resume, R.drawable.settings};

    for (int count = 0; count < heads.length; count++) {
        DashModel dashModel = new DashModel();
        dashModel.setHead(heads[count]);
        dashModel.setSub(subs[count]);
        dashModel.setImage(images[count]);
        dashModelArrayList.add(dashModel);
        //this should be retrieved in our adapter

    }
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2));
    dashAdapter = new DashAdapter(dashModelArrayList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(dashAdapter);
}}
```

Adapter class :

```
public class DashAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DashAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<DashModel> dashModelArrayList;

public DashAdapter(ArrayList<DashModel> dashModelArrayList) {
    this.dashModelArrayList = dashModelArrayList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String ret_head = dashModelArrayList.get(position).getHead();
    holder.setheader(ret_head);

    String ret_sub = dashModelArrayList.get(position).getSub();
    holder.set_sub(ret_sub);

    int ret_image = dashModelArrayList.get(position).getImage();
    holder.set_image(ret_image);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dashModelArrayList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView header,sub_header;
    ImageView images;
    View myView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myView = itemView;
    }

    public void setheader(String h)
    {
        header = myView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        header.setText(h);
    }

    public void set_sub(String s)
    {
        sub_header = myView.findViewById(R.id.sub_header);
        sub_header.setText(s);
    }
    public void set_image(int i)
    {
        images = myView.findViewById(R.id.dash_image);
        images.setImageResource(i);
    }


}}
```

How can i add onItemclickListener here?

I expect and want to add OnItemclickListener in the icon but i can't and don't know how to add.

Comment: could you please post your DashAdapter

Comment: i update with adapter class please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `onClickListener` for RecyclerView you have to create a class which implements the `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`

```
import android.support.v7.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class RecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerViewTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface ClickListener{

        public void onClick(View view,int position);
        public void onLongClick(View view,int position);
    }
}
```

After that you can attach it to your `RecyclerView` to listen for clicks.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerViewTouchListener.ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method


        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
        }                                           
    }));
```

Comment: is any possible solution for String heads[] = {"Jobs", "My Profile", "Messages", "Applied Jobs", "Resume", "Settings"};
actually i want to add onitem click listener in this array

Comment: Your are showing the heads[] array in the recyclerview, so you can make a onClickListener for the recyclerView using my answer.